# Span is slow (not optimized correctly)

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I have this situation here:

```
public class Bla<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    private unsafe T* _data;
    private int _dataLength;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => Span[index];
        set => Span[index] = value;
    }
    public unsafe Span<T> Span => new Span<T>(_data, _dataLength);
}
```

The class above has a pointer to some data, and a field specifying the data's length. There's also a property `Span`, which just merely creates a new `Span` to `_data`.

Now in a benchmark calling the indexer of `Bla` billions of times, I found that it was around **20%** slower than this:

```
public class Bla<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    private T[] _data;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => _data[index];
        set => _data[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Note that in both examples, `_data` is allocated the **exact** same way. The problem here is clear; creating a new `Span` every time we want to access `_data` is not optimal.

The reason why I am creating a `Span` every time in the indexer is because of safety. A span provides some necessary bounds checking which accessing via pointers does not.

I could just add an if statement to check the bounds, but that makes it almost **2x** slower than the Span method. (just checks if index is less than 0 or equal to length)

What can I do to get `C#` to optimize the code better? Or is it even possible? I have tested `.NET 5` and `.NET 6.0 Preview 4`, both with similar results.

Comment: `Memory<T>` can live as a field in your class. Probably a better choice for your indexer. Leaving Span for anywhere you might want to access multiple elements.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Unfortunately I cannot create `Memory<T>` from a pointer, and also `Memory<T>` doesn't even have an indexer.

Comment: How on earth does boundary checking double the processing time? Are you using floating point or something? If your current logic takes the same amount of time as an integer comparison, it's already going lightning fast.

Comment: @JohnWu I think it has something to do with branch prediction. I was just doing 2 simple integer comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constantly creating the span instance is indeed, not free (even if it is a value type). We can't see the calling code, but I would *anticipate* that if that code was tweaked to avoid the indexer, and instead fetch the span *once*, and perform multiple operations on that span - this may help, especially for `for`/`foreach` loops over the data. Note also that if `Bla<T>` is only used transiently, it may be possible to write it as a `ref struct`, the significance of this being that a `ref struct` can *store the span as a field directly* (instead of the pointer and length), avoiding some overheads.

In particular, when restructuring consuming code to consider spans: SIMD. In many cases you can usefully coerce a span to a vector type (via `MemoryMarshal`) to perform additional optimizations using block operators.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to get C# to optimize the code better?

Have you considered that there is no way to optimize the code better? You want additional functionality (bounds checking). Your own implementation is slow, the .NET implementation is already way ahead of you in terms of optimization, but you don't get additional functionality at the same speed. That is just not going to happen. More code, more instructions, more cycles executing them.

If you posted a full program that you use to measure, we could probably say more, but from just looking at it, it seems that you will have to decide if you want to give up bounds checking for speed or be safe but a little slower. That problem has been around for ages, way before computers. Safe *and* fast is not possible, you have to prioritize one over the other.

Comment: However, if you use _data as an array, then it's much more performant yet still maintaining safety. Is there any way to get an array from a pointer?

Comment: I guess it all depends on what you want to do? I the data behind the pointer immutable? Do you have the memory? Then *copy* it into whatever form you need. That is a one-time on-instantiation cost. Might be worth it. Maybe not. We cannot tell.

Comment: @nvoigt just to say: a span is almost always preferable to copying something; the whole "zero copy with arbitrary memory" is *why spans exist*